# Problem with natbib and class based on scrbook

Tags: natbib, scrbook, package-options

I'm building a class for monographs, dissertations, and thesis from my department. I chose as a base the scrbook class that is part of koma-script. I need the natbib package numbers option to be called by a class option of the same name. I do not understand why the following example minimal does not work

The class Estilo. File Estilo.cls.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\ProvidesClass{Estilo}[21/06/2018 UFRRJ monografias, dissertações e teses]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{scrbook}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass[fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\RequirePackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\DeclareOption{numbers}{\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers}{natbib}}
```

File Teste.tex

```
\documentclass{Estilo}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    
\begin{document}    
    Uma gravação em pedra encontrada em Karnak-Egito
\end{document}
```

When compiling this example we find the following error:

```
LaTeX Error: \RequirePackage or \LoadClass in Options Section
```

If the last line of the Estilo.cls class is commented the compile is successful, without any error message, warning or bad box.

I do not understand why this mistake happens. Could someone help me understand and, if possible, point out a solution.

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Try moving your declare option command before processoptions.

Comment: The instructions `\DeclareOption{numbers}{\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers}{natbib}` have to come *before* the `\RequirePackage[sort&compress]{natbib}` instruction. In fact, all three instructions can be combined into a single instruction: `\RequirePackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mico, but the problem persists in any order that puts the commands. Would you have another suggestion? I need to implement it as shown in the example to meet the rules of university composition. I thought of an alternative like that.

Comment: \newif\if@loadrefnum
    \DeclareOption{refnum}{\@loadrefnumtrue}
    \if@loadrefnum
          \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
     \fi  
Without the commands                                                 
    \RequirePackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
    \DeclareOption{numbers}{\PassOptionsToPackage{numbers}{natbib}} But it did not work, it gives the same error

Comment: @Mico That's not equivalent, is it? I assumed that `numbers` was optional and not to be hard-coded.

Comment: You need the `\DeclareOption`s before `\ProcessOptions` - before `\DeclareOption*`, probably. You need the `\RequirePackage`s after `\LoadClass`.

Comment: Are you sure you want people not to be able to use Biblatex/Biber for their dissertations? Is there a good reason for this?

Comment: @cfr - The `sort&compress` option really makes sense only if used in combination with the `numbers` option -- the latter option sets up numeric-style citation call-outs, and "sorting and compressing" refers to a way the citation call-out numbers could be displayed.

Comment: @BenaiaSobreiradeJesusLima - After making the suggested change, did you delete all auxilliary files before attempting to recompile?

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Although they were not a solution, they helped me build a solution. Thank you very much.

If anyone has an interest in my solution you can contact me, or if moderators allow I can post here